# Django Channels error : failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: django, python-2.7, websocket, webfaction, django-channels

I am using Django with django channels. I am going off of Andrew Godwins django channels examples the "MultiChat" example. I am using Webfaction and Putty to try and get it going here is the code I got.

settings.py

```
redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')

CHANNEL_LAYERS = { 
     "default": { 
         # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis 
         "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer", 
         "CONFIG": { 
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 27411)], 
         }, 
         "ROUTING": "myproject.routing.channel_routing", 
     }, 
}
```

I do have a question here would I change were it says localhost to my Ip address for my website or would i leave it as localhost when using redis?

as for my index.html I have this Not sure if this code needs to be tweaked or updated any help is appreciated thanks.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}
{% block header_text %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <ul class="rooms">
        {% for room in rooms %}
            <li class="room-link" data-room-id="{{ room.id }}">{{ room }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <p class="empty">No chat rooms defined. Maybe make some in the <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a>?</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <div id="chats">
    </div>

{% endblock %}


{% block extra_body %}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Correctly decide between ws:// and wss://
            var ws_path = "/chat/stream/";
            console.log("Connecting to " + ws_path);

            var webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
            webSocketBridge.connect(ws_path);
            // Handle incoming messages
            webSocketBridge.listen(function(data) {
                // Decode the JSON
                console.log("Got websocket message", data);
                // Handle errors
                if (data.error) {
                    alert(data.error);
                    return;
                }
                // Handle joining
                if (data.join) {
                    console.log("Joining room " + data.join);
                    var roomdiv = $(
                            "<div class='room' id='room-" + data.join + "'>" +
                            "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
                            "<div class='messages'></div>" +
                            "<form><input><button>Send</button></form>" +
                            "</div>"
                    );
                    // Hook up send button to send a message
                    roomdiv.find("form").on("submit", function () {
                        webSocketBridge.send({
                            "command": "send",
                            "room": data.join,
                            "message": roomdiv.find("input").val()
                        });
                        roomdiv.find("input").val("");
                        return false;
                    });
                    $("#chats").append(roomdiv);
                    // Handle leaving
                } else if (data.leave) {
                    console.log("Leaving room " + data.leave);
                    $("#room-" + data.leave).remove();
                    // Handle getting a message
                } else if (data.message || data.msg_type != 0) {
                    var msgdiv = $("#room-" + data.room + " .messages");
                    var ok_msg = "";
                    // msg types are defined in chat/settings.py
                    // Only for demo purposes is hardcoded, in production scenarios, consider call a service.
                    switch (data.msg_type) {
                        case 0:
                            // Message
                            ok_msg = "<div class='message'>" +
                                    "<span class='username'>" + data.username + "</span>" +
                                    "<span class='body'>" + data.message + "</span>" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // Warning / Advice messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-warning'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            // Alert / Danger messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-danger'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // "Muted" messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            // User joined room
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username +
                                    " joined the room!" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            // User left room
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username +
                                    " left the room!" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log("Unsupported message type!");
                            return;
                    }
                    msgdiv.append(ok_msg);

                    msgdiv.scrollTop(msgdiv.prop("scrollHeight"));
                } else {
                    console.log("Cannot handle message!");
                }
            });

            // Says if we joined a room or not by if there is a div for it
            inRoom = function (roomId) {
                return $("#room-" + roomId).length > 0;
            };

            // Room join/leave
            $("li.room-link").click(function () {
                roomId = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
                if (inRoom(roomId)) {
                    // Leave room
                    $(this).removeClass("joined");
                    webSocketBridge.send({
                        "command": "leave",
                        "room": roomId
                    });
                } else {
                    // Join room
                    $(this).addClass("joined");
                    webSocketBridge.send({
                        "command": "join",
                        "room": roomId
                    });
                }
            });

            // Helpful debugging
            webSocketBridge.socket.onopen = function () {
                console.log("Connected to chat socket");
            };
            webSocketBridge.socket.onclose = function () {
                console.log("Disconnected from chat socket");
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

my error

```
(index):40 Connecting to /chat/stream
websocketbridge.js:118 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.openchat.us/chat/stream' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
connect @ websocketbridge.js:118
(index):161 Disconnected from chat socket
websocketbridge.js:183 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at ReconnectingWebsocket.send (http://www.openchat.us/static/channels/js/websocketbridge.js:183:12)
    at WebSocketBridge.send (http://www.openchat.us/static/channels/js/websocketbridge.js:364:19)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (http://www.openchat.us/:149:37)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (http://www.openchat.us/static/channels/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js:3:12444)
    at HTMLLIElement.r.handle (http://www.openchat.us/static/channels/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js:3:9173)
(index):1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.openchat.us/chat/stream' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
2(index):161 Disconnected from chat socket
2websocketbridge.js:118 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.openchat.us/chat/stream' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
connect @ websocketbridge.js:118
(index):161 Disconnected from chat socket
```

Answer (score 0):

If your redis is at the same place than your wepapp, you can set `localhost` as redis IP address.

- You talked about Putty, are you on remote machine  ?
- Does your redis is listening to the same port than define into `settings` ?

Comment: Hi Mathieu yes redis is installed on a machine provided by webfaction I am using putty to ssh into the machine in there i have installed redis, ya with webfaction I have to use Putty to ssh into the webfaction machine and the thing with redis is when i put in the command ./redis-server it starts it into 127.0.0.1:6379 but when using django channels I have to enter the command daphne -p { } myproject.asgi:channel_layer # the port being the port from the websocket app from webfaction  thus making me want to start redis with ./redis-server -p {myportumberhere}

Comment: my current error is: Connecting to ws://www.openchat.us/chat/stream/
reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.openchat.us/chat/stream/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
open @ reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1
a @ reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ (index):49
i @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
(index):164 Disconnected from chat socket